# Application defined or object defined error (named ranges)

Tags: excel, vba

Im stumped at this point with my code here, im getting this generic error at the line where its supposed to copy and paste the selected range after creating the worksheet but its giving me this frustrating error - i dont know what im doing wrong here, please help guys, all help appreciated :)

```
Private Sub ExpBttn()

Dim WrkShtExists As Boolean
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim TgtRngR As Range
Dim TgtRngB As Range
Dim TgtNme As String

Select Case Multi
Case MultiPage1.Value = 0
    Set TgtRngR = Sheets("Tracker").Range("U2:Z19")
    Set TgtRngB = Sheets("Tracker").Range("U21:Z26")
    TgtNme = "P4PSoft"
Case MultiPage1.Value = 1
    Set TgtRngR = Sheets("Tracker").Range("AB2:AG19")
    Set TgtRngB = Sheets("Tracker").Range("AB21:AG26")
    TgtNme = "P4PHard"
Case MultiPage1.Value = 2
    Set TgtRngR = Sheets("Tracker").Range("AP2:AU19")
    Set TgtRngB = Sheets("Tracker").Range("AP21:AU26")
    TgtNme = "RCI"
Case MultiPage1.Value = 3
    Set TgtRngR = Sheets("Tracker").Range("AI2:AN19")
    Set TgtRngB = Sheets("Tracker").Range("AI21:AN26")
    TgtNme = "RCDI"

End Select

Sheets.Add.Name = "Exported_" & TgtNme

Sheets("Tracker").Range("TgtRngR").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Exported_" & TgtNme).Range("A1:F18")
Sheets("Tracker").Range("TgtRngB").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Exported_" & TgtNme).Range("A20:F25")
Sheets("Exported_" & TgtNme).Range("A1:F18") = Sheets("Tracker").Range("TgtRngR").Value
Sheets("Exported_" & TgtNme).Range("A20:F25") = Sheets("Tracker").Range("TgtRngB").Value
Sheets("Exported_" & TgtNme).Select
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:F").AutoFit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your range variable in the Case statement, so use it in the copy/paste

```
TgtRngR.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Exported_" & TgtNme).Range("A1:F18")
```

and

```
Sheets("Exported_" & TgtNme).Range("A1:F18") = TgtRngR
```

Also, your Case statment logic is incorrect.  It should be something like

```
TgtNme = ""
Select Case MultiPage1.Value
Case 0
    ...
Case 1
    ...
'etc
End Select

If TgtNme <>"" then
    ' do the cop pastes
End If
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot that worked like a charm. Yes I'm a noob as you can clearly see :D thanks so much i really didnt know where to go with this but the response time and the knowledgble people here make me feel great! You sir, are my hero. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please review your `Case` statement:

- in the `Case` opener you use a (local) variable `Multi`
- in the contition statements you use a different object `MultiPage1.Value`
- both of them are not declared

For me it looks as none of the `Case` branches are executed and hence `TgtRngR`, `TgtRngB`, `TgtNme` are undefined.

Setting a breakpoint at `Private Sub ExpBttn()` and stepping through the `Sub` with F8 would help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the super fast reponse I got it :) youre awesome